# Barcode in MVC3 with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, barcode

Technologies: Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports, MVC3 Web Application, multi tier app.

My web app build one report to label print. The report works fine but not generates the bar code. When I view the report the barcode field is blank. I already installed the IDAutomationHC39M and works in winforms project.

The code that generates the report:

```
    public void Barcode()
    {
        BarCode report = new BarCode();
        Barcodes barcodeDetails = new Barcodes();

        DataTable dataTable = barcodeDetails._Barcodes;
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
            string nome = "nome" + i;
            decimal preco = i;
            string barcode = i + "ADF" + i;

            row["nome"] = nome;
            row["preco"] = preco;
            row["barcode"] = barcode;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        report.Database.Tables["Barcodes"].SetDataSource((DataTable)dataTable);

        report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "crReport");

    }
```

Is more easy transform the barcode in a jpeg? If yes, how can i make this in crystal reports?

**EDI I:** I try change the code for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                string nome = "nome" + i;
                decimal preco = i;
                string barcode = "*" + i + "ADF" + i + "*";

                row["nome"] = nome;
                row["preco"] = preco;

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 80))
                {
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                    {
                        Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 10);
                        PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                        SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                        SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                        graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                        graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
                    }
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                        Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        row["barcode"] = imgBarCode.ImageUrl;
                    }
                }



                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

But no effects.

Comment: I'd hate to ask, but did you set the crystal report field to use the IDAutomationHC39M font you installed?

Comment: This approach works only in winforms, because the font is installed in a local machine. In web app  the barcode is created in server and only visualized on client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process to display barcodes in asp.net app (MVC in my case) is really transform the font in an jpeg.

Step 1: get the value for barcode and add "*" in start and end, then creates the Bitmap, Font and Graphics.

```
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

                string barcode = "*" + ID.ToString() + VALOR_VENDA.Value.ToString() + "*";

                row["nome"] = NOME_PRODUTO;
                row["preco"] = VALOR_VENDA.Value;

                int w = barcode.Length * 40;
                Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(w, 100);
                Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);
                Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 18);
                PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);
                oGraphics.DrawString(barcode, oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);
```

Next use an MemoryStream to add the bitmap. Make sure that your dataset field is the type Byte[]. With the memorystream add to dataset the value .ToArray();

```
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    oBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                    row["barcode"] = byteImage;
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```